# Can I access a storage account blob-URL via my Azure Point 2 Site VPN?

Tags: networking, azure, azure-storage, azure-vpn

I have a storage account in Azure that has network security enabled, meaning only selected networks can access the storage account.
I also have a Azure point 2 site VPN for which I have given its subnet access to the storage account (as part of the 'selected network' to is allowed).

In practice I often create SAS tokens for download blob URL's, but those are blocked now obviously. Can I route my calls from my local computer to the download blob URL's via my point 2 site VPN so that access is allowed?
Also, the IP-whitelisting feature is not an option due to dynamic ip's of everyone needing access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your using the Service Endpoints feature for storage Firewall then no, you cannot access this over your VPN. Service Endpoints on support traffic coming directly from an Azure vNet, not any networks connected via VPN or Express Route.

However, if you can switch to using [Private Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints) for your storage account then these are accessible from connected networks over VPN and Express Route.